# MySQL: Search range of strings with slash

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a varchar field with the following data:

Interface
Gig1/0/1
Gig1/0/3
Gig1/0/5
Gig1/0/10
Gig1/1/11

I am trying to do a search (BETWEEN).

```
Select * from test1 where Interface Between "Gig1/0/1" and "Gig1/0/5"
```

Returns all the records except for Gig1/1/11

Comment: Would your query also return Gig1/0/10? That isn't really between 1/0/1 and 1/0/5 assuming regular integers.

Comment: They're not regular integers; they're strings. Think of it as 'GigB/A/B' and 'GigB/A/F'  Isn't 'GigB/A/BA' between them? Yep!

Comment: That query returned Gig1/0/1, Gig1/0/3, Gig1/0/5, and Gig1/0/10. Gig1/0/10 should not be there. The field is a varchar (string).

Comment: hopefully I'm not making a fool of myself here but what does Gig1/1/11 represent ? Should it be a normalised set of data ?

Comment: It is a naming scheme from CISCO; Managment Interface name. I guess it could be normalized but the creator doesn't want to make any changes to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the substring_index function?

```
select substring_index(fieldname,'/',-1) as v from tablename where v between 1 and 5
```

Comment: That works: select interface  from test1 where substring_index(interface,'/',-1) between 1 and 5, but only if I am searching for the last numbers before the right most slash. Can't search for Gig1/1/11.

Comment: ...assuming I had more records like Gig1/1/10, Gig1/1/5... How would I search for those?

Comment: perhaps using "select substring_index(fieldname,'/',-2) as v from tablename where v between '0/1' and '1/5'" as this would select 1/10,1/15 etc.